# What are the differences between the "Special Rehearsal Edition" and the "Official Playscript" of the Cursed Child?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, edition-comparison

*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* is currently available in two print versions:

- [Special Rehearsal Edition Script](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1338099132) (released July 31, 2016)
- [The Official Playscript of the Original West End Production](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/133821666X)* (released July 25, 2017)

What are the differences between these two versions?

<sub>* This was [originally announced](https://wizardsandwhatnot.com/2016/06/07/second-definitive-edition-of-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child-confirmed/) as the "Definitive Edition".</sub>

Comment: Maybe it's like the "director's cut" of movies? But that's just a guess.

Comment: @Fabian I'm fairly sure it's the difference between the original script and the shooting script in movies. The former was created first and shopped around, the latter fixes things and is what actually made it onto the set and into the movie. I would expect the Official Playscript to have alterations to fix problems discovered during rehearsal: difficult lines made easier and cleaner, pacing issues, that sort of thing. The question here is: What exactly were those fixes?

Comment: Mostly it's just very, *very*, minor changes in dialogue and stage directions. I tried compiling a list once, but it was too painful.

Comment: Minor edits and changes for the express purpose of selling the same content to the same people for even more money . . .

Comment: @PatDobson - If anything it was the first copy that was sold for the express purpose of selling something twice. Who sells the "rehearsal" edition of a script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Most of the changes were extremely minor tweaks in stage direction and/or dialogue.

- A lot of the stage directions were expanded and/or changed.

  > **2016:** *ALBUS is asleep in a hospital bed. HARRY sits troubled beside him. Above them is a picture of a concerned kindly man. HARRY rubs his eyes — stands — and walks around the room. **He stretches out** his back.*
  >
  > **2017:** *ALBUS is asleep in a hospital bed. HARRY sits, troubled, beside him. Above them is a picture of a concerned, kindly man. **A picture keeping a careful eye on them both.** HARRY rubs his eyes, stands, and walks around the room, **stretching** his back.*
  >   <sub>Act 2 - Scene 8</sub>
- Some Dialogue was minorly changed. A few lines were added, removed, and/or shifted to other characters.

  > **2016:** SCORPIUS: How did Cedric become a Death Eater? What have I missed? Find me some — light in the darkness. **Tell me your secrets. What have I missed?**
  >
  > **2017:** SCORPIUS: How did Cedric become a Death Eater? What have I missed? Find me some — light in the darkness.
  >   <sub>Act 3 - Scene 4</sub>
  >
  > **2016:** HERMIONE: A daughter.
  >
  > RON: **And a son.** I liked that idea too.
  >
  > **2017:** HERMIONE: A daughter **and a son.**
  >
  > *He smiles gently at her, their love is true and total.*
  >
  > RON: I liked that idea too.
- Some of the weird creepy parts were toned down by a slight notch.

  > **2016:** ALBUS/RON: Or if not another baby, a holiday. I want a baby or a holiday and I’m going to insist on it. Shall we talk about it later, honey?
  >   ***She tries to get into the room one final time, he blocks her with a kiss. It develops into quite a struggle.***
  >
  > **2017:** ALBUS/RON: Or if not another baby, a holiday. I want a baby or a holiday and I’m going to insist on it. Shall we talk about it later, honey? 
  >   <sub>Act 1 - Scene 18</sub>
  >
  > **2016:** MOANING MYRTYLE: I think it was a secret, but I could never keep anything from you, Harry. How is it you’ve grown handsomer and handsomer as you’ve aged? **And you’re taller.**
  >
  > **2017:** MOANING MYRTYLE: I think it was a secret, but I could never keep anything from you, Harry. How is it you’ve grown handsomer and handsomer as you’ve aged?
  >   <sub>Act 2 - Scene 19</sub>
- A "conversation about reading scripts" between author Jack Thorne and director John Tiffany was added to the beginning.
- A rudimentary timeline and family tree were added to the end.

Comment: Could you please give an example of dialogue being shifted to another character? I'm curious about that. Also, you say that "most of the changes were extremely minor". Does that mean that there were *any* that were not minor, like changes to the plot?

Comment: @Thunderforge - I added one example. I remember seeing one or two more direct examples, but I can't find them now and rereading CC is *really* painful. There were no changes to the plot. A few minor nuances in characterization, and the expanded stage directions explicitly confirm things that were previously only implies (e.g. Voldemort still being alive in  the AU.) If you want more information just run the two ebooks through any basic text comparison software.